# WPF Directory Not Found Exception and PresentationCore.pdb not loaded

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I am trying to add a background image to a textbox but on textChange event, the image goes away as expected, however if I backspace or delete text in the textbox so that it is empty, I get the `DirectoryNotFoundException` was handeled.
 And the directory:

*Could not find a part of the path 'C:\myProjectFolder\bin\Debug..img\txtBackground.png'.*

**The XAML:**

```
<TextBox Name="myTextBox" Width="200" TextChanged="myTextBox_TextChanged">

<TextBox.Background>
<ImageBrush ImageSource="img/txtBackground.png" />
</TextBox.Background>
```

**C# Code:**

```
private void myTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
if (myTextBox.Text == "")
{
ImageBrush textImageBrush = new ImageBrush();
textImageBrush.ImageSource =
new BitmapImage(
    new Uri(@"..img/txtBackground.png", UriKind.Relative)
);
myTextBox.Background = textImageBrush;    
}
else
{
myTextBox.Background = null;
}
}
```

Deleted the references, re-added them, build/clean solution and rebuild but nothing.
These errors only occur when I try to add the background to the textbox.

Comment: the img folder that has image, is it Debug folder?

Comment: Yes I added the img folder to the Debug folder.

Comment: ideally you should add img folder to your project and add images to that with BuildAction as Resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the img folder that has image is under the Project (not under the debug folder, ideally it should not be in Debug folder) and image's BuildAction is set to Resource, you can try this:

```
new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/img/txtBackground.png", UriKind.Absolute));
```

If you have img in Debug folder then you have to reach upto that

```
new Uri(@"bin/Debug/img/txtBackground.png", UriKind.Relative)
```

Comment: Actually this worked: But I changed the above from this:
new BitmapImage(Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/img/txtBackground.png", UriKind.Absolute));

To this:
new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/img/txtBackground.png", UriKind.Absolute));

Comment: Thank you so much: The image is not in the debug folder, I removed it, it is under the project folder. The build action is set to: Resources. Thank you so much: This was a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Your Uri should read

```
new Uri(@"/img/txtBackground.png", UriKind.Relative)
```

At least that's what the error message says.

Comment: I tried that but still get the error: I have other images in the project that are referenced like that: ../img/imagename and they work fine.

Comment: Then you are missing a slash in your path? Look at the uri you provided, it says "..img", not "../img"

Comment: I have tried that in every way possible: ../img/image or img/ or /img and I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
textImageBrush.ImageSource =new BitmapImage("/Projectname;Component/img/txtBackground.png");
```

The image's `Build Action` must be set to `Resource`.